# Dynamiclly Element Clone And Remove in Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, clone

I am working on jquery and working on clone and remove element.

The clone context is working fine but I am unable to remove element context.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div[name="addnewrow"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1) {
      var cp = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
      $(cp).find('div[name="addnewrow"]').text('-');
      $(cp).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().val(''));
      $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      $('div[name="addnewrow"]').text('+');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="sound">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Sound File<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
      <select name="moh_file_path" id="moh_file_path" data-parsley-required="" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">DEF</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-danger" name="addnewrow"> + </div>
  </div>
</div>
```